# Compute $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]$ of two dependent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $(X,Y)$ be a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with density
> $$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = e^{-(x+y)}\mathbb{1}_{A}(x,y)$$
> where $A = \{(x,y): 0\leq y \leq x\}$.

> 1. Determine if $X$ and $Y$ are independent
> 2. Compute $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]$

So far, what I found the two marginals
$$f_{X}(x)= e^{-x}-e^{-2x}$$
and
$$f_{Y}(y) = e^{-2y}$$
and concluded that the two random variables are not independent, since the product of the marginals doesn't correspond to the above density.

However, having $X$ and $Y$ not independent causes me some problems in solving point 2.

I proceeded as follows:

$\mathbb{E}[(Y-X)^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2 -2XY + X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - 2\mathbb{E}[XY] + \mathbb{E}[X^2]$

$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \int_y^\infty x^2f_X(x)dx$

$\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = \int_0^x y^2f_y(x)dy$

But I have doubts on how to compute $\mathbb{E}[XY]$. My idea was $\mathbb{E}[XY]= \int_0^x \int_y^\infty xy f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)dxdy$
but this doesn't feel right.

What is the right way to compute it?

Thanks in advance for any help

You can see the original text here:

[image]

Comment: I do not know why someone downvoted my answer but, also after your amendment your $f(x,y)$ is not nice because its integral over the joint domain is evidently not 1. I repeat that the 2 rv's cannot be independent as their joint domain is not a rectangle

Comment: @tommik I think too that the integral isn't nice. At first I thought that the domain wasn't correct and that it would be the joint pdf of two independent exponential r.v.'s. But I was told that it is right in this way and that I couldn't receive any hints about it

Comment: if the domain is what you stated, you have to multiply $f(x,y)$ by 2 to get a nice density. I would have answered you checking all the rest, but due to the downvote I  deleted my answer

Comment: @tommik i'd be happy to upvote if you undelete your answer :)

Comment: @Miresh It would be better if you would show us the source text.

Comment: @callculus I added the picture of the problem. It doesn't change much from what I wrote, but if it can help, it's there

Comment: @Miresh: there is a typo in the text... sometimes it happens

Comment: @Miresh My problem is that $$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \int\limits_y^{\infty} e^{-(x+y)} \ dx \ dy=0.5\neq 1$$ I would contact the lecturer and ask her/him if there is somewhere a typo.

Comment: @tommik I guess you are right and it's them who made a typo. I'll ask them again and make them notice what you told me. Thank zou so much for your help

Comment: @callculus thank you too, I'll ask them again and as I said above, I'll make them notice this

Comment: @Miresh OK. Maybe you can leave a comment about their answer.

Comment: Update: they agreed on the fact that the density isn't correct, but told me to solve the exercise with it anyways.

Comment: @Miresh Thanks for the reply. Interesting, their position: This is not a density, so what. Just ignore it, but compute the density of $ X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain is the infinite triangle you stated,

[image]

the correct joint density is

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-x}e^{-y}$$

The calculation of the marginal densities is not needed to realize that the 2 rv's are not independent. In fact, observing their joint domain, a necessary condition for independence is that it is a rectangle. As it is a (infinite) triangle they cannot be independent. This is very easy to understand because if the joint domain is a triangle it is self evident that the domain of one marginal changes w.r.t. the occurence of the other one.

The expectation you have to calculate can be derived using the definition

$$\mathbb{E}[(Y-X)^2]=\int_0^{\infty}\left[\int_0^x (y-x)^2f_{XY}(x,y)dy  \right]dx$$