# Calculate the marginal

Tags: random-variables

I want to calculate the marginal $f_X(x)$ of $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = 2 e^{-(x+y)} \mathbb 1_A (x,y)$ where $A = \{(x, y): 0 \leq y \leq x \}$.

It is clear that I have to integrate $f_{X, Y}$, but how do I handle this "$\mathbb 1_A (x, y)$" at the end?
Sorry for the stupid question, but since this seems very basic to me, it's important that I understand how to compute these things.

Comment: this recent discussion can be also  useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128208/compute-mathbbex-y2-of-two-dependent-random-variables?noredirect=1#comment8539057_4128208

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition you get

$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{XY}(x,y)dy$$

that in  your case is

$$f_X(x)=2e^{-x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-y}dy=2e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})$$

the other marginal is

$$f_Y(y)=2e^{-y}\int_y^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=2e^{-2y}$$

that is $Y\sim Exp(2)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explications and calculations! I knew it has to be simple...now it's clear. Thank you! :)

Comment: Btw: Shouldn't it be: $Y \sim exp(-2)$?

Comment: @StMan What??? $Y$ is a negative exponential with density $f_Y(y)=\theta e^{-\theta y}$ thus $\theta=2$

Comment: Oh yeah, excuse me. You're right (Y).

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do, is to apply the set $A$ in your integration. In this case,
$$
f_X(x)=\int_{y\ :\ (x,y)\in A} 2e^{-x-y}dy=\int_0^x 2e^{-x-y}dy.
$$
If you wished to find $f_Y(y)$, it should be
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_{x\ :\ (x,y)\in A} 2e^{-x-y}dx=\int_y^\infty 2e^{-x-y}dy.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explications! I knew it has to be simple...now it's clear. Thanks! :)

Comment: Happy to help ;)